# Trying to think of a way to dynamically add text for each image

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to think of a way to make this happen.

I'm using a jQuery slideshow to display images, and a simple php script to pull the images from a folder based on which gallery the user selects:

```
    $handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/../images/gallery/'.$gallery);
while($file = readdir($handle)){
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
        $pictures .= '<img src="images/gallery/'.$gallery.'/'.$file.'" alt="" />';
    }
}
```

I'm doing it this way since there are 6 different galleries, and the amount of photos in each gallery varies, from about 25 - 40 pictures. If I did the site staticly, or had a database running it'd be no problem, but I can't think of a PHP way of doing this.

Basically here is an example of what I'm hoping to do: [I hard coded all the images and text](http://diguiseppi.com/Brad/index.php?cat=Create&do=International-Gallery)

But on [this page](http://diguiseppi.com/Brad/index.php?cat=Create&do=Gallery) I can't think of a good way of doing it

Comment: Where would the ALT text come from?

Comment: It's not per say "alt text..." It's more like "fluff text" about the image particular image... And not every image will have text.

Answer (score 2):

You can add to each folder file like `info.txt` with descriptions. Check file_exists() on load and get data from the file.

If you want to set desc for each photo you can do smth like:

For files:

- flower.jpg
- cloud.jpg
- girl.jpg

info.txt:

```
flower.jpg::This is flower
cloud.jpg::This is cloud
girl.jpg::This is girl
```

So you read info.txt, explode by rows and explode rows at last. At the result you're getting array with descriptions and filenames.

Comment: A variation on this is to have a text file per image.  So if you had `flower.jpg` you could have `flower.jpg.txt`, which contains the description of that single image.  (Instead of one text file for all images in a directory).

Comment: so basically do something like: "data-caption="#___ID__"" into the image tag?

Comment: Is there a working example of this, so I can see how it would work?

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the best way to do it, but heres my work-around way I accomplished it:`
I renamed the images: 
01-A Bird, 02-A Cat

```
$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/../images/gallery/'.$gallery);
while($file = readdir($handle)){
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){

        $alt = substr($file, 3, -4); //Removes the "##-" and the ".jpg"
        $id = substr($file, 0, 2); // Removes EVERYTHING after the "##"

    // The image
        $pictures .= '<img src="images/gallery/'.$gallery.'/'.$file.'" alt="'.$alt.'" data-caption="#cap'.$id.'" />';
    // The text
        $span .= '<span class="caption" id="cap'.$id.'">'.$alt.'</span>';

    }
}`
```